# How did people trade for food and drink in Bronze age cities?

Tags: economy, money, bronze-age, mesopotamia

The time period I’m specifically interested in is Mesopotamian civilizations in the early to middle bronze age, but I don’t mind examples from other comparable cultures.

I’m curious how people in societies that, at least according to the sources I’ve read, appeared to have had no cash money made small purchases. I know that much of commerce was based on debt/credit, but I am primarily interested in the following scenarios:

- A citizen wants to go for a beer with his friends at the local tavern
- A foreigner with no local connections wants to buy a meal on the
  market, and get a place to stay for the night
- A citizen wants to pay for a prostitute

For the locals, I can imagine them just keeping a tab, but still I wonder if that’s how it was commonly done. If so, how would that work for a foreigner? I’ve read that oil or barley were commonly used as proto-currency, but I cannot imagine that everyone would carry around a flask of olive oil or a measure of barley to pay for a snack.

Sources I have considered:

- [Mesopotamian contracts](https://sourcebooks.fordham.edu/ancient/mesopotamia-contracts.asp) - only covers big transactions
- [barter economy](https://history.stackexchange.com/a/64488/59304) - close but not quite there, and a bit handwavy. Comments also mention [Debt: The first 5000 years](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debt:_The_First_5000_Years), which seems to only consider person-person transactions, and not person-business, as would be the case with a tavern

Comment: Not quite Mesopotamia, but possibly relevant. Genesis 38:15-17: *Judah saw her and thought that she was a prostitute, for she had covered her face. He headed over to her and said, “Let me sleep with you.” He did not know that this was his daughter-in-law. She said, “What will you give me to sleep with me?” He said, “I will send a goat from the flock.”*

Comment: Jared Kelly, "The Beverage of the Ages: The Role and Function of Beer in
Sumerian Society", *Armstrong Undergraduate Journal of History*, Vol. 9, No. 2, Nov. 2019, Article 1: " *Sumerians understood beer could be used as a currency as it had an intrinsic value, was easily divisible, could serve as a unit of account, and as a result could be used as a medium of exchange. Around 3,500 BCE, in the Sumerian city of Uruk, there is evidence of residents bartering with beer, trading the beverage for more scarce and precious resources such as precious stones, timber, and metal* "

Comment: A bit of info here: https://factsanddetails.com/world/cat56/sub363/item1514.html

Comment: @CarlosMartin wow, that's an amazing resource, thanks for linking it. It's unfortunate that these kinds of resources are (at least for me) quite hard to google.

Comment: @njuffa Thanks for the examples.

Comment: From that doc, it sounds like your foreigner would be out of luck without local contacts and/or the resources to buy local tokens.

Comment: I've scanned the facts-and-details article, and I think the information in there is enough to satisfy my question. @CarlosMartin, you can write an answer based on it that I'd accept. If you don't feel like it I'll self-answer eventually.

Comment: @Arne I don't know enough about it to write a good answer